# Should I use nested collections to organize my backbone.js app?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having a bit of a tough time wrapping my head around backbone. I want to use it to deliver data based on different races in different cities.

So, Ideally, I would have a collection of cities, and each item in the collection would be a collection of races in that city, composed of candidates (I think). AM I on the right path?

My data feed is just an array of objects, with various identifying key: values.

```
Example:
var data = [
{
  'name': 'John Smith',
  'race': 'Mayor',
  'city': 'York'
},
{
  'name': 'Jack Black',
  'race': 'Mayor',
  'city': 'York'
}, 
{
  'name': 'Billy Bob',
  'race': 'Mayor',
  'city': 'Trenton'
} ,
{
  'name': 'Burt Reynolds',
  'race': 'Mayor',
  'city': 'Trenton'
}
]
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Can you read [ask] and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Backbone does not support nested models/collections very well, and in your use case, I don't see why it would be necessary.

One way of doing what you want to accomplish would be to create one collection of all of your data, then use the .where method to get the information you want when you are ready to manipulate/display it.  For instance, create a collection of all of your data, lets refer to it as MyCollection, then if you want to deliver data based on the Mayor race in Trenton, you could say something like var trentonMayorRace = MyCollection.where({race: 'Mayor', city: 'Trenton'})  and this will return an array of models that match those attributes.